# git config settings to automatically create remote branch with same name

Tags: git, git-config

I used to have my git set up very nicely where it would automatically push to the remote branch with the same name when I ran `git push`, and automatically pull when running `git pull`.

I tried to show a friend how to do this and in the process managed to break my own config. How can I get back to the functionality I'm looking for? I've tried a bunch of configs, but each has its problems.

I currently have this in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[push]
    default = current
[branch]
    autoSetupMerge = always
```

But when I create a new branch locally, then commit and push, it says "Everything up-to-date". If I then run `git push origin <branch_name>` it does push the changes.

These settings don't seem to do the trick either:

```
[push]
    default = matching
[branch]
    autoSetupMerge = always
```

Answer (score 19):

You can configure it with `git config --global push.default current`
to make it push the current branch to update a branch with the same name.

But, in 2022, and with a git version *git >= 2.37.0*, you can specify this in your git config `git config --global --add --bool push.autoSetupRemote true` and this achieves the same while also setting up the upstream tracking.

Comment: nitpick: `git config --global -push.autoSetupRemote true` should suffice (but +1)

Comment: typo on nitpick: `git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true`, removing the extra `-` in front of `push`

Comment: I would enhance this answer with one additional point: If you're using `push.autoSetupRemote true`, then you almost certainly also want `branch.autoSetupMerge simple`, which will ensure your branching operation only sets a tracking branch if your new branch has the same name. Without this, your `git pull` behavior is strange/different during the short time between the original branching, and the first push.

Comment: This git config set up  command did the following change :
It set up : 
      [push]
 autoSetupRemote = true
in my global  .gitconfig

Answer (score 16):

You can use following command to instruct git to by default create remote branch with same name (I have used global level, you can decide level based on your requirement:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

[source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault)

you can  use -u option for first time push for new branch, it will help in tracking of new branch and will help while pulling changes. If you did not use -u for first time push, you can use it for later push also. Basically, tracking will start after a push with -u option.

```
git push -u
```

without specifying origin and branch name for new branch and push changes.

Comment: In the past I had it working fine without the -u option. `git push` was enough

Comment: You will just need it for first time. then you can use git push as usual.

Comment: simple and straight to the point. Good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The main control knob here is indeed `push.default` and you probably want either `current` or `matching`, which have this very-major difference:

- `current` means that if you omit the refspec argument(s), your Git should use the branch you are on right now—the one `git status` would say "on branch ...", or that `git branch` would print with an asterisk—and try to push that to its upstream counterpart.  That is, if the current branch is `xyz`, the `current` setting will ask `origin` to set its `xyz` branch (your upstream) to the same hash ID as your `xyz`.  **This is true even if the upstream for your `xyz` is their `zyx`**—see `upstream` below.
- `matching` means that if you omit the refspec argument(s), your Git should get a list of branch names from their Git.  Then, for each of their branch names—whatever they are; `master`, `develop`, `zyx`, and so on—your Git should see if you also have a branch with the same name, regardless of what your branch's hash ID is.  For each matching *name*, your Git should ask their Git to set *their* branch to the same hash ID that *your* Git shows for that name.

The `matching` setting means that, for instance, if you run:

```
git push ssh://host.example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

and they have branches `master`, `develop`, and `zyx`, and you have a `master` and `develop` but no `zyx`, your Git will ask them to set *their* `master` and `develop` to match your `master` and `develop`, even if their Git is completely unrelated to your Git.

(If their Git is unrelated to yours, this polite request will certainly fail, so that's not that big a deal.)

You can explicitly ask for `matching` behavior on any given push, without setting the `push.default` setting, using:

```
git push <remote> :
```

That is, a bare colon `:` as a refspec means "matching".

The remaining `push.default` settings, which are `nothing`, `upstream`, `tracking`, and `simple`, are mostly variants on `current`:

- The `nothing` setting just errors out entirely if you omit a refspec.  I used this for a while but found it to be too annoying.
- The `upstream` and `tracking` settings are synonyms—`tracking` is a deprecated synonym for `upstream`—and mean *use the upstream setting of the current branch to determine the name to send to the other Git*.  Hence if your `forward` has `origin/reverse` as its upstream, you'll ask them to update their `reverse`.
- The `simple` setting mean the same thing as both `upstream` *and* `current`, picking which one to emulate based on where you're `git push`-ing to: it checks whether the remote you're using is the one for which the remote is set, and if so, behaves like `upstream` except that it requires that the branch names match.  Otherwise, it behaves just like `current`.

I leave mine set to `simple` these days, and just run `git push -u origin HEAD` when pushing a new branch on purpose, and `git push` with no parameters when pushing to a same-named branch.

Comment: Till a week ago I had it set up so that `git checkout -b my_branch && git push` would just work. Same for `git pull`. None of the settings I've tried give that functionality.

Comment: `matching` won't *create* a branch, because it's not matching. `current` *will* create the branch, but only if you're *on* it. Also, note that any global setting can be overridden by any local setting; you can also set a default refspec for a particular remote with `remote.<name>.push`, which will override other `push.*` settings.

Comment: I think it may be a local setting overriding it actually. On another project and things are working as I like. `current` being the right option. Will look to see what happened for the other project next week.

Comment: You can use `git config --show-origin --get-all push.default` to show every config file that sets `push.default` and to what, based on your current repository. That will show any system setting first, then any `--global` setting, then any `.git/config`-based setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit your .gitconfig by hand, something like

```
[push]
    autoSetupRemote = true
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Isn't this what the command in the top-voted answer does?

Comment: Yeap, exactly. Just shared in case one is curious to know how it'd look like in `.gitconfig`.